# Why I got : The final variable 'd' can only be set once. Try making 'd' non-final using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, list, dart, split, final

I'm on mixing two lists using flutter I declare a variable as final and when I tried to reuse it I got : The final variable 'd' can only be set once.Try making 'd' non-final.
And I want it to be as final.
this is my code :

```
final d = [];
    chunks.forEach((chunk) {
      final c = chunk as List<int>;
      final list4 = [(c[c.length - 2] ^ c[c.length - 1])];
      d = c + list4;
    });

    print('List With CRC : $d ');
    return d;
  }
```

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
List d = [];
        chunks.forEach((chunk) {
          final c = chunk as List<int>;
          final list4 = [(c[c.length - 2] ^ c[c.length - 1])];
          d = c + list4;
        });
    
        print('List With CRC : $d ');
        return d;
      }
```

Comment: I got LateInitializationError: Local 'd' has already been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

In flutter, final variables can only be set once.
In your code, you change it's value multiple times when you do this in a loop:

```
d = c + list4;
```

So, you either remove the final keyword, or limit yourself to set it's value only once.

Comment: but how can I fix this issue ?

Comment: Again, you either remove the final keyword, or limit yourself to set it's value only once

Comment: Is there any solution to limit myself to set it's value only once on my case !! beacause I tried but I didn't get the solution

Comment: You could use a temporary list, let's call it `d_temp` that you insert the values into, instead of `d`. Then, once the loop is over, do `d = d_temp;`